# Unzipping several specific files out of many into a directory using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, zip

I recently installed Linux Mint 17 on my laptop. I had Windows 7 before, and I backed up all of my data onto an external hard drive. Windows 7 crams all of your backup data into a ton of .zip folders. Here is my problem: I only want to extract those folders that contain my music, which lie in the path `C:\...\Username\Music...`. So I tried to find a way to use the unzip those files from my external hard drive and into my Music directory in my home folder using the terminal. I am still learning how to use the terminal, but this is what I have found:

```
for file in *.zip; do unzip -c "$file" -d "/~/Music" | grep "\Username\Music"; done
```

It gives me the output:

```
caution:  not extracting; -d ignored
```

When I remove the `-d`, it works, (well, seems to work: it ran for a while), but I get a weird output at the end and then this:

```
62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c
```

I searched for the music that was supposedly unzipped but could not find it. Can anyone tell me if and how I can accomplish my goal? I'd like to unzip only my music files from my external hard drive to my Music folder.

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` flag of unzip means *extract files to stdout/screen*, so no files are actually written to disk and hence the `-d` option is meaningless - it may also explain the strange characters you are seeing in the terminal. Perhaps you are thinking of the `-C` (*use case-insensitive matching*) modifier?

Rather than using `grep`, probably what you want is to supply an *optional list of archive members to be processed* following the zipfile: also you likely need use Unix-style `/` path separators, even if the zipfile's origin is a Windows system.

Finally, "/~/Music" will likely be interpreted as a literal absolute path; you probably need `~/Music/` or `"$HOME/Music/"` - the latter form being more easily modified to target directories with spaces in them e.g. `"$HOME/My Music/"`

```
unzip -C "$file" '*/Username/Music/*' -d "$HOME/Music/"
```

Note however that this will probably result in a folder structure like `~/Music/Username/Music/somefile`, which might not be what you intend. AFAIK `unzip` doesn't have the same flexibility to strip leading directory components that some implementations of `tar` do, however you may wish to look at the `-j` modifier.